# Appending rows in a database using toad and excel

Tags: mysql, toad

Friends, I am using toad for MySQl, and have a huge database ready and validated.
Now i have an excel file which contains data-entries for a particular table. And i am also successfully able to import data into the db using import wizard, mapping the first row header with the column names etc.
But now i have appended a few data entries into it which i wish to insert into the database. However the old values also get selected and hence cause a primary_key_violation exception as the entry already exists! Otherwise a truncate table option is there which i dont wish to use as there may be many files from which i have inserted the data.
I tried my level best but didnt get any solution, atleast in toad for mysql. Please tell me what to do! the solution maybe simple but i need it SOS

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to not append records to that excel file, but create a new excel file with only the new records

Comment: yeah, but that truncates the previous file